# Pass context through composed promises in KJ

Tags: c++, promise, capnproto, kj

Playing with the KJ library, I wrote a small TCP servers that reads a "PING" and responds a "PONG". I managed to compose the promises like this:

```cpp
char buffer[4];
kj::Own<kj::AsyncIoStream> clientStream;

addr->listen()->accept()
    .then([&buffer, &clientStream](kj::Own<kj::AsyncIoStream> stream) {
      clientStream = kj::mv(stream);
      return clientStream->tryRead(buffer, 4, 4);
    }).then([&buffer, &clientStream](size_t read) {
      KJ_LOG(INFO, kj::str("Received", read, " bytes: ", buffer));
      return clientStream->write("PONG", 4);
    }).wait(waitScope);
```

I had to keep `buffer` out of the promises and pass a reference to it. This means that `buffer` has to stay in scope until the last promise finishes. That's the case here, but is there a solution in case it isn't?

Same thing for `clientStream`: I had to declare it before, then wait until I receives it from `accept()`, and at this point move it outside and use the reference to it.

Is there a better way to do it? Say like a way to pass some kind of context from promise to promise, always owned by the promises and therefore not having to stay "outside"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is that your second lambda wants access to the scope of the first lambda, but the way you've organised things prevents that. You've worked around that by just adding variables to their shared "global" scope.

Instead, you could put the second lambda inside the first, something like this:

```
addr->listen()->accept()
    .then([](kj::Own<kj::AsyncIoStream> stream) {
      auto buffer = kj::heapArray<char>(4);
      auto promise = stream->tryRead(buffer.begin(),4,4);
      return promise.then([stream=kj::mv(stream), buffer=kj::mv(buffer)] (size_t read) mutable {
        KJ_LOG(INFO, kj::str("Received", read, " bytes: ", buffer));
        return stream->write("PONG", 4);
      });
    }).wait(waitScope);
```

Comment: Hmm it fails to compile the `stream->write()` line with `error: passing ‘const kj::AsyncIoStream’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers`

Comment: yeah, lambda captures are const by default, try that edit

Comment: as you can see, didn't set up a test project for this one, but once the details are fixed i think the idea will work